# Syntax error in updated 0.12 react docs?

Tags: reactjs

When I try and run the [Transferring with ... in JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#transferring-with-...-in-jsx) example

```
var FancyCheckbox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var { checked, ...other } = this.props;
    var fancyClass = checked ? 'FancyChecked' : 'FancyUnchecked';
    // `other` contains { onClick: console.log } but not the checked property
    return (
      <div {...other} className={fancyClass} />
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <FancyCheckbox checked={true} onClick={console.log}>
    Hello world!
  </FancyCheckbox>,
  document.body
);
```

I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. Same when I try to run it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke4bmqny/1/)

Is this an error or is some extra code transpilation required for this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use this feature you have to have [harmony enabled](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/03/21/react-v0.10.html#react-tools). Unfortunately the fiddle integration you're using is not having it enabled.

There is a [commit made recently](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/0f5368341ff96c88c3fbef57dfa089b43d129a06) which adds it, so very likely it will be up there.

If you want to use it right away, you can either host the file somewhere, or just add the script directly to the fiddle:

```
<script>
  (function () {
    var tag = document.querySelector(
            'script[type="application/javascript;version=1.7"]'
    );
    if (!tag || tag.textContent.indexOf('window.onload=function(){') !== -1) {
      alert('Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle');
    }
    tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/jsx;harmony=true');
    tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace(/^\/\/<!\[CDATA\[/, '');
  })();
</script>
```

The important line is `'text/jsx;harmony=true'`. [Check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke4bmqny/2/).